# MySQL таблица с отделением по группам

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Добрый день!
Имеется таблица многие ко многим `id|date_id|model_id|status|group_id`.
Каким образом можно составить запрос к БД, чтобы потом получить следующий результат(буду рад любой ссылке):

[image]

Comment: Колонок ДатаN всегда 4? Или об это не надо думать, и разворот таблицы в несколько колонок будет выполняться php скрипторм?

Comment: @alexlz, ДатаN будет динамической (php скрипт, но думаю, есть возможность составить запрос на стороне базы).

Comment: @idd Если количество колонок переменно, то запросы должны быть разными для каждого количества колонок (хотя их можно на регулярной основе формировать в php). Тогда на выходе mysql будут колонки Имя_группы, Имя, Дата1, Дата2, ...
и сортировка по Имя_группы, Имя.